# how to extract text in each line of a pdf file using python

Tags: python, pdf

I have gone through many solutions for extracting data from pdf file but could not find a solution to this particular problem

I have a pdf file that has the following data format in it

```
UPC             Product Description              Subcategory Name   Pkg type

018894300199    Big Y Mozzarella String  16oz       16oz Pkg Cheese    PKG
```

[image]

I need to extract the UPC, Product description and Sub name for each line of the pdf file using python

I was able to extract the text from the pdf file using the code below

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter



pdfFileObj = open('grocery2.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)


print(pdfReader.numPages)

pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
pagecontent = pageObj.extractText()
```

I have more than 500 pages of product data. what is the most efficient way of extracting the UPC, Product description  and Sub name for each line of the page?

Comment: Could you show us what the output text looks like? we need to spot a separator to use, are all strings just distinguished by spaces or..?

Comment: @JesseBarnett yes they are distinguished by spaces. the only separator I could think of is using "PKG" at the end of the line to separate each line

Answer (score 0):

Since they are distinguished by spaces and your strings themselves have spaces using the extracted text will probably not be too helpful. I would have to see the full pdf to know if this would work but try:

```
From tabula import read_pdf

df = read_pdf("grocery2.pdf")
```

Then you can do any dataframe operations to extract different values *ie.*

```
df1 = df[['UPC', 'Product Description']]
```